# How to optimize my site for mobile users?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So, made my site, tried optimizing it for mobile users too, but no luck. Note that I'm a beginner at website development, self-taught. I'm here to learn :) Followed few guides/tutorials, something on my own and so on. I'm open for suggestions and constructive criticism :) Thanks in advance!

I'll paste everything here:

```js
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
    
    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        //Toggle Nav
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        //Animate Links
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
                link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.3}s`
            }    
        });
        //Burger Animation
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');
    });
    

}

navSlide();
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 4vh;
    background-color: #a44949;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.logo{
    color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.nav-links{
    display: flex;
    width: 30%;
    justify-content: space-around;

}
.nav-links li{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav-links a{
    color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.burger{
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.burger div{
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
    margin: 5px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width:1024px){
    .nav-links{
        width: 45%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){
    body{
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .nav-links{
        position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            height: 92vh;
            top: 8vh;
            background-color: #a44949;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            align-items: center;
            width: 50%;
            transform: translateX(100%);
            transition: transform 0.5s ease-in;
    }
    .nav-links li{
        opacity: 0;
    }
    .burger{
        display: block;
    }

    .banner{
        width: 50%;
    }
}

.nav-active{
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade{
    from{
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to{
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1{
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px,6px);
}
.toggle .line2{
    opacity: 0;
}
.toggle .line3{
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px,-6px); 
}

.banner{
    width: 100%;
    
}

.text-box{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    background: rgb(250, 250, 250);
    margin-top: -4px;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 240px;
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.text-uvod{
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    font-size: 28px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.footer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: repeat(1, min-content);
    grid-auto-flow: column;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 74.48%;
    margin-left: 240px;
    margin-right: 240px;    
    justify-content: space-around;
    min-height: 28vh;
    background-color: #a44949;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
}

.footer-list{
    display: block;
    justify-content: space-around;
    list-style: none;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.heder{
    justify-content: space-around;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.mapouter{
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    padding-top: 7px;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}

.gmap_canvas{
    overflow: hidden;
    background: none;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <title>MD Auto Delovi</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head> 
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <h4>Rakić MD</h4>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li>
          <a href="#">O nama</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Lokacija</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <img src="pics/banner.png" class="banner">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <div class="text-box">
      <p class="text-uvod">Auto Delovi Rakić, bavimo se putničkim i teretnim programom. Cilj nam je da zadovoljimo kupca sa cenama i kvalitetom proizvoda. Radimo sve poznate brendove.<br>
        Ulja i maziva koja su nam se najbolje pokazala u prodaji su Mogul ulja za putnički i teretni program. Takođe, radimo i ostale brendove.<br>
        Garancija na svaki kupljeni proizvod!<br>
        Trudimo se da ispoštujemo svakog kupca sa ljubaznošću i kvalitetom delova.<br>
        Hoćemo da budemo tim i da sa lakoćom rešimo svaki problem koji vas muči.<br>
        Sigurni smo u sebe i mi to možemo, proverite i nećete se pokajati!<br>
        Hvala na poseti,<br>
        Vaši Auto Delovi Rakić MD 021</p>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <div><h4 class="heder">Kontakt</h4>
        <ul class="footer-list">
          <li>Mobilni : 062/329-077</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div><h4 class="heder">Podaci</h4>
        <ul class="footer-list">
          <li>PIB : 112295370</li>
          <li>Matični broj : 66007057</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div><h4 class="heder">Radno vreme</h4>
        <ul class="footer-list">
          <li>Pon-Petak : 08:00-18:00h</li>
          <li>Subota : 08:00-14:00h</li>
          <li>Nedelja: Neradna</li>
        </ul>
        </div>
      <div><h4 class="heder">Lokacija</h4>
      <ul class="footer-list">
        <li>Oslobođenja 32c, Rumenka 21201</li>
      </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mapouter">
        <div class="gmap_canvas">
        <iframe width="250" height="250" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d701.68692485527!2d19.739371629239997!3d45.293319842130856!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x475b137d0ce980cd%3A0x17a15ebc1c9edeb6!2sRaki%C4%87%20MD%20Auto%20Delovi!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1615383981122!5m2!1sen!2sus" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. So is not a forum, tutorial or guide. Its for develoeprs that already can code and need help with a specific coding issue. For example debugging help. You post lacks research efford aswell as a specific doing issue. If you want to optimize a website for mobile use, you should read about media queries and repsonsive webdesign

Comment: PS: Without more details and clarity to specify a problem, this question can be considered opinion-based. `how to improve` is a very broad question that will lead only to opinion based anwsers

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines to your CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .text-box {
    margin: 0 6px;
  }
  .text-uvod {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  .footer {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

**@media** is used to apply styles only when a certain condition is met.
In this case, styles that would make footer and text-box fill the entire screen are only applied when the window's width is smaller than 1200 pixels.